# While publishing test report in Azure devops getting error

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, hp-uft, uft14

> "#[error]System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'Invoke-ReportTask' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

I have integrated azure devops with uft but the result i am not getting in Azure devops.

How to show the test result in azure devops after the uft test cases run successfully?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Hugh Lin.I am not able to Publish the test report generated by UFT in Azure devops.Even if i have used Azure devops plugin ie Publish test result..Still not able to publish.Please help me  on this.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT....Can you please help on this above issue.

Answer (score 0):

After a test run, UFT automatically saves the run results as an artifact with the build.

So you need to add an additional **Copy/Publish Artifact** step and specify the options for this step from the **Utility** tab.

Navigate to the build artifacts specified in the Copy/Publish Artifact step and locate the **results.html** file to view the test results.

[image]

For details ,please refer to **View the test results** part of this [document](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.50-14.53/UFT_Help/Content/UFT_Tools/Azure_DevOps_Extension/uft-azure-devops-run-local.htm).

Comment: I want the report should display in Azure devops pipeline under Test tab.Its displaying for Selenium and katalon test cases but in case of UFT no result showing